# Growl iNotify not working

Tags: python, growl

I just downloaded Growl 1.2.2 dog in an attempt to get the GrowlInotify extra so I can start using pyautotest. Problem! I don't get any growl notifications from the [custom test runner](http://www.ianlewis.org/en/modipyd-growl-test-driven-development). I tried running growlinotify directly on the cmd line and it is silent.

```
growlnotify -m "testing"
```

Runs silently and produces no growl window. Am I missing something obvious? I should mention that I purchased the latest version of Growl from the Appstore for $1.99 a few months back and have kept it up to date but I have not purchased the hardware growler. (I don't even know what it is or what the difference is.)

Answer (score 0):

I've finally figured out why things weren't working for me. I had downloaded and installed growliNotify from Growl 1.2.2 which is incompatible. After revisiting the Growl downloads page and scrolling down a little further I found the growliNotify package for growl 1.3+. I installed this and now growlinotify works from the command line as expected. Also the custom test runner is also now sending growl messages!